# Making the background of a JFrame window white by commenting out the data in the paint method

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I was practicing making a JFrame window and stumbled upon an issue. The tutorial video i was watching said to comment out the data given in the paint method in order to make the background of the window, white insdead of grey. When I did that, the window turned transparent and it captured whatever was displayed on your computer and set it as the window's background. The vided  was posted in 2012 so, i believe that there have been some advancements in Eclipse that caused the problem. So, **how can i change the background colour of a JFrame window to white?**

Comment: Well, I'd just like to say - it's a stupid video for even suggesting do such a dumb thing - don't watch any more from that author.  If you want to make the window content white, why not set the background color of the `contentPane`? Or set the `contentPane` to a component whose background you've set to white

Answer (score 2):

> So, how can i change the background colour of a JFrame window to white?

Start by changing the `backgroundColor` of the `contentPane`, for example

[image: Red is the new white]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
    
    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*nb I made it red to make the point...

This is limiting though, because, unless you change the layout manager, the moment you add a component to it, it will be covered.

A "better" solution might be to make a component and change it's `backgroundColor` and add it to the frame

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }
}
```

or even make it the `contentPane`, what ever you need.

> i believe that there have been some advancements in Eclipse that caused the problem

Eclipse has nothing to do with it.  Will either be changes made to the JRE or OS

> said to comment out the data given in the paint method

Okay, painting is complicated process, with a number of important steps, unless you have a clear understanding of what those steps are AND are willing to take over from them and do their jobs, don't mess with it ;)